# Identify these insects hiding under compost

Tags: compost, insects, outdoor

I use a layer of compost as mulch, but every time I water, millions of tiny insects start jumping all over the place. Is it possible to identify them as I'm not sure if they're decomposing the organic matter or hurting the plants.

https://youtu.be/7wNxCE56jKE

Comment: I think you are going to need to catch some and take still photos.

Comment: How do the plants you are watering look- any sign of problems?

Comment: Where do you live in the world?

Comment: It will be quite challenging to catch, they're really tiny, try to play the video at a reduced speed, maybe? @EvilElf

Comment: @Bamboo no specific signs except some deficiencies that I'm trying to fix.

Comment: @Jurp Tunisia - North Africa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like springtails. Not a problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail

With one exception they dont harm plants, and eat bacteria, fungi, and decomposing matter.

The exception is the lucerne flea - but that lives on the branches and leaves.